# Working with Matlab functions in C++ (for matrix searching)

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

What I want to do is searching a 2d matrix inside a bigger 2d matrix. For that, I have found a 2d version of Boyer-Moore algorithm.
But working with matrices in matlab is always easier, so I was wondering if I can call matlab functions in a C++ compiler.

i think people here know how to do it in matlab. 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/247971

Is there a library or something that exists for this purpose? which contains at least the functions used by the programs given in the link above.

PS: if anybody can provide the solution for this searching problem, please do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for in the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f38569.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries for this, you might have more luck checking the matlab website to see if they sell development libraries.

As for a solution, this problem seems conceptually very similar to that of finding substrings in strings.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1556747/1277769) while searching briefly, I'm sure it could help.

As for a basic solution, one could go something like this:

You want to find an `p x q` submatrix inside an `n x m` matrix.

```
    for each row (up to row n - p):
      search each column (up to column m - q)
        if value in matrix equals first value check the rest of the submatrix
          if submatrix found, exit or store solution and keep looking for more
```